# How can I have for loop do things not in nested way?

Tags: clojure

I want to have something like

```
(for [x [1 2 3]
      y [4 5 6]]
      (+ x y))
=>(5 7 9)
```

instead of

```
=>(5 6 7 6 7 8 7 8 9)
```

I suppose I could do it with destructuring but not sure how.
I tried

```
(for [[x y] [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]] (+ x y))
```

which gives (3 9).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: in Clojure, you should think recursive, not iterative.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm still learning to think functionally.

Comment: for is a functional list comprehension - it's name causes confusion, because of for-loops in imperative languages

Comment: @m0skit0 I'd go a bit further and say, "think functional" - a la @dbyrne's answer using `map`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for` macro isn't the most suitable choice for this problem.  Try using `map`:

```
(map + [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
```

Comment: Well, that doesn't solve the more general problem: sometimes `for` *is* more suitable because you need to do multiple nested steps, but you want one of the steps to combine two seqs. Another solution would be `(for [[x y] (map vector [1 2 3] [4 5 6])] (+ x y))`.